# Can't release iMessage extension in AppStore because of missing Messages framework

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, imessage

I implemented iMessage extension in my ios project, but after submiting and reviewing my build i see following in iTunnes connect: "Your binary doesn’t implement the Messages framework. The screenshots won’t be shown on the App Store for iMessage."
[image]

I tried to add it in main target but still problem is there
[image]

I'm quite confused what i should do, as i have it worked in simulator and test device.
May i need to change something in my build schema or settings? Thanks in advance for any advices.

Comment: Have you checked into your MessageExtension target if the library is present?

Comment: @RomOne yes, it's there as well http://screencast.com/t/K3SWpJ4Rl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out that i added a new target instead of extension (http://screencast.com/t/32hMPE8NWeR)
To fix that you need to add your iMessage extension to Target Dependencies and .appex file to Embed App Extensions in Build Phases
[image]